# How to move a directory, file by file? (instead of "copy then remove")

Tags: files, scripting, rename, file-copy

My computer has one 500GB drive.

I want to move 400GB of data from `/unencrypted` to `/encrypted`.

Both directories are on the same partition, but `/encrypted` is handled by [ecryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org), so `mv /uncrypted/* /encrypted` would:

1. Copy all files to destination
2. Then remove them from source

...which I can't afford, because it requires 800GB.
If files were moved one-by-one, there would be no problem (the ecryptfs zone is dynamic).

Is there an `mv` option or another tool, that moves a directory file-by-file?
There is a huge number of files, so ARG_MAX might be a problem for script-based solutions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have `rsync` (remove `--dry-run` to do it for real):

```
rsync --dry-run --remove-source-files -avHAX /unencrypted/ /encrypted
```

Otherwise, using bash4+ and GNU stat:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

shopt -s nullglob globstar

for from in /unencrypted/**/*; do
    to="${from/\/un//}"
    if [[ -d "$from" ]]; then
        echo mkdir -p "$to"
        echo chmod "$(stat -c %a "$from")" "$to"
        echo chown "$(stat -c %u:%g "$from")" "$to"
    else
        echo cp -a "$from" "$to" && echo rm "$from"
    fi
done

echo rm -r /unencrypted
```

To run it for real, remove `echo` from each command.

Comment: I love the rsync idea! Apparently files are indeed removed as they are moved: http://superuser.com/questions/405761

Comment: @NicolasRaoul If I recall correctly, the removals are buffered, but it is close to one-to-one copy/remove.

Comment: Chunks are fine for me, as long as each chunk weights less than 50GB.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to remove `--dry-run` from the rsync command line, too?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I thought that was implicit, apologies if it wasn't. I'll note it.

Comment: I went the rsync way. Two problems but general success. 1) One file had a name a name just long enough for ext4 but too long for ecryptfs. Renamed. 2) Got a black screen of death http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/1057/rsyncfreeze.jpg controls not reacting anymore. First time I see this. Anyway, I waited until the disk stopped blinking, then rebooted, and checked that there were no more files at source with `find . -type f`

Comment: @NicolasRaoul That traceback seems related to the transfer, but it's difficult to work out exactly what happened from that alone. You might want to fsck your filesystems.

Comment: could you comment on your choice of the "avHAX" arguments in rsync?

Comment: @meduz `v` is optional and just prints the filenames as they are transferred. `aHAX` is required to keep all possible file attributes -- `a` is archive, `HAX` is "keep hardlinks, ACLs, and extended attributes".